# what is the structure of a JSON file loaded into R? Should I treat it as a list?

Tags: r, json

The content of this JSON file is like the below:

```
{
    "data":[
        {"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"},
        {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"},
        {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"},
        {"Manitoba":"MB","MB":"1.28"},
        {"Saskatchewan":"SK","SK":"1.1"}
    ]
}
```

I expect to access the single value of each of them so I can find the province with largest population.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries for loading JSON data. One of the most common ones is `{jsonlite}`, when using it for parsing without any simplifications, a list will be returned that matches the structure of the JSON:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
json_str <- '
{
    "data": [{
            "British Columbia": "BC",
            "BC": "4.63"
        }, {
            "Alberta": "AB",
            "AB": "4.15"
        }, {
            "Ontario": "ON",
            "ON": "13.6"
        }, {
            "Manitoba": "MB",
            "MB": "1.28"
        }, {
            "Saskatchewan": "SK",
            "SK": "1.1"
        }
    ]
}
'
# parsing json with jsonlite, simplifications disabled
jsonlite::parse_json(json_str) |> glimpse()
#> List of 1
#>  $ data:List of 5
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ British Columbia: chr "BC"
#>   .. ..$ BC              : chr "4.63"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ Alberta: chr "AB"
#>   .. ..$ AB     : chr "4.15"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ Ontario: chr "ON"
#>   .. ..$ ON     : chr "13.6"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ Manitoba: chr "MB"
#>   .. ..$ MB      : chr "1.28"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ Saskatchewan: chr "SK"
#>   .. ..$ SK          : chr "1.1"
```

That particular structure with variable keys is bit annoying to work with,
but as there are just 2 key/value pairs per item, we could turn it into rectangular data.frame with something like this:

```r
# from each item in data build a tibble row with 3 columns,
# bind rows
df <- jsonlite::parse_json(json_str) |> 
  pluck("data") |>
  map(\(x) tibble_row(prov = names(x)[1], 
                      code = x[[1]], 
                      value = as.numeric(x[[2]]))) |> 
  list_rbind()
df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   prov             code  value
#>   <chr>            <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 British Columbia BC     4.63
#> 2 Alberta          AB     4.15
#> 3 Ontario          ON    13.6 
#> 4 Manitoba         MB     1.28
#> 5 Saskatchewan     SK     1.1

# get a row with highest value in `value`
slice_max(df, value)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   prov    code  value
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Ontario ON     13.6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>