# How to create a R dataframe in a desired format with the given json file

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I have a json file with the following content

```
{"data":[{"Alpha":"A","A":"4.63"}, {"Beta":"B","B":"4.15"}, {"Omega":"O","O":"13.6"}, {"Theta":"T","T":"1.28"}, {"Sigma":"S","S":"1.1"}]}
```

It looks like this after loading into R:

```
library(jsonlite)
> data <-fromJSON("provdata.json")$data
> data
  Alpha    A    Beta  B      Omega  O      Theta  T     Sigma   S
1   A    4.63   <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
2  <NA> <NA>     B   4.15    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
3  <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>     O  13.6      <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>
4  <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>      T  1.28      <NA> <NA>
5  <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>      S   1.1
```

I would like to extract the name Alpha, Beta, Omega, ... and put them in the first column of a dataframe. And extract the value 4.63, 4.15, 13.6, ... and put them in the second column. The desired output would be:

```
> restructured_data
          Name        Value
1         Alpha       4.63
2         Beta        4.15
3         Omega       13.60
4         Theta       1.28
5         Sigma       1.10
```

Comment: Kudos for changing key values :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/77208630/646761

Comment: @margusl yes, of the three duplicates of this homework question, this one has slightly more effort made to obfuscate it, even if not to try and solve it!  It's a good first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read-in the JSON data with `simplifyDataFrame = FALSE` and obtain
a `list` instead of the sparse `data.frame`. Now you can process the `list`,
and built the `data.frame` to your specification.

```r
library(jsonlite)
json_data <-
  '{"data":[{"Alpha":"A","A":"4.63"}, {"Beta":"B","B":"4.15"}, {"Omega":"O","O":"13.6"}, {"Theta":"T","T":"1.28"}, {"Sigma":"S","S":"1.1"}]}'
df1 <-
  fromJSON(json_data, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)$data

library(tidyverse)

map(df1,
    \(x) tibble(name =  names(x[1]),
                value = x[[2]])) |>
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Alpha 4.63 
#> 2 Beta  4.15 
#> 3 Omega 13.6 
#> 4 Theta 1.28 
#> 5 Sigma 1.1
```